# Retrieve Cookie Data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have the  following function :

```
    public function check_daily_data() {
            $month = $this->input->post('month');
            echo 'Month :' . $month . '</br>';
            $year = $this->input->post('year');
            echo 'Year :' . $year . '</br>';
            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('employee_id');
            echo 'User Id : ' . $user_id . '</br>';
            //load the cookie helper
            $this->load->helper('cookie');

                setcookie("month", "", time()-3600);
            setcookie("year", "", time()-3600);
            $time = time()+3600;
            $cookie_month = array(
                'name' => 'cookie_month',
                'value' => $month,
                'expire' => '3600',
                'secure' => TRUE
            );
            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie_month);

            $cookie_year = array(
                'name' => 'cookie_year',
                'value' => $year,
                'expire' => '3600',
                'secure' => TRUE
            );
            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie_year);

            var_dump($this->input->cookie('cookie_month')); 
            $cookie_months = $this->input->cookie('cookie_month',TRUE);
            echo 'Cookie Month : ' . $cookie_months . '</br>';

            $cookie_years = $this->input->cookie('cookie_year',TRUE);
            echo 'Cookie Year : ' . $cookie_years . '</br>';
}
```

When I run the script and check the cookie variable using FireBug, I can be able to view the cookie data but when I try to echo it, I get a blank value. 
The var_dump returns a false, please can you advise what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well, why you are not getting value is because, you have set `'secure' => TRUE`. you need to set it up to `false`. the true setting will work only with `HTTPS`

```
$cookie_month = array(
                'name' => 'cookie_month',
                'value' => $month,
                'expire' => '3600',
                'secure' => FALSE
            );

 $cookie_year = array(
                'name' => 'cookie_year',
                'value' => $year,
                'expire' => '3600',
                'secure' => FALSE
            );
```

then you will get your value when you call

```
$cookie_months = $this->input->cookie('cookie_month',TRUE);
```

Comment: I have done so but still I cannot be able to echo the  cookie values but I can view the cookie values from firebug

Comment: Try a var_dump of $cookie_years and $cookie_months ?

Comment: I still get a bool(false) from the $cookie_years and $cookie_month variables

Comment: well, why you are not getting value is because, you have set 'secure' => TRUE. you need to set it up to false. the true setting will work only with HTTPS